# Swiftにおいて、let data = "test".data(using: .ascii)! というのは何をしている処理ですか？

Tags: swift

タイトルのままなのですが、Swiftにおいて以下のような記述を見かけました。

```
let data = "test".data(using: .ascii)!
```

ネットワークを介して文字列を送信するためにいったん変換しているようなコードの一部で使われていました。
これは、どのような処理を行っているのでしょうか？
文字列を何らかの形で別の型のようなものに変換しているように見えるのですが
usingの"ascii"が何を示しているのか、何故"utf-8"などを使っていないのかなどもよく分かりません。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String`型の[`data(using:)`メソッド](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1416696-data)を呼ぶことによって、文字列を表すバイナリーデータに変換しています。文字列をどんなバイナリーデータで表すかはエンコーディングによって違うので、それを指定できるようになっています。

例えばご質問中に記載された例だと、`data`は、次のような中身を持つバイナリーデータになります。

```
| 0x74 | 0x65 | 0x73 | 0x74 |
(   t      e      s      t  )
```

Swiftではバイナリーデータを表すのには`Data`型を使うことが多いので、`data(using:)`の結果も`Data`型となっています。

どんなエンコーディングを指定するかは、送信の相手先がどんなエンコーディングを期待しているかに合わせないといけません。ただ`"test"`のように、ユニコードのコードポイントがU+0000からU+007Fの範囲の文字は、`.ascii`でも`.utf8`でも結果が同じになるので、「エンコーディングはUTF-8」と指定されている相手先に、`.ascii`を指定する人もいるようです。

---

変に言葉を重ねると逆に分かりにくくなるかと思って編集しているうちに、なにか中途半端な説明になってしまったような気もします。分かりにくいところがあれば、コメント等付けていただけるようお願いします。

Comment: とても丁寧に回答して頂きありがとうございます。バイナリデータになっているのですね。ユニコードのコードポイントがU+0000からU+007Fの範囲の文字は、.asciiでも.utf8でも結果が同じになるとのことですが、その範囲でない場合は何が異なってくるのでしょうか？

Comment: @gncc さん、「その範囲でない場合」`.ascii`なら結果が`nil`になります。コード例のように`!`がついているとそこでクラッシュですね。`.utf8`の場合は、1文字が2〜4バイトのデータになります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。ということは、基本的にはutf8の方がよくて、asciiにするメリットはあまり無いと考えた方が良いのでしょうか？処理速度等には少し影響があったりするかもしれないという感じでしょうか？

Comment: 基本的には送信先がUTF-8が欲しいと言ってれば(インターネットの規定上自動的にUTF-8になると言う場合を含めて)必ず`.utf8`を使います。処理速度なんて測ったことはないんですが、あったとしても微小なんで気にすべきものでもないです。本来UTF-8のところに`.ascii`を使ってしまうのは、中途半端な経験がある人の悪しき習慣だと思ってください。